# AngularJS insert invalid HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that requires HTML to be pieced together from different APIs. Rather than getting into specifics there, let me just say that we have tried getting away from that many times but in the end the best answer always end up being what we currently have. Hopefully that changes someday but for now it's working great.

Currently, the HTML is parsed together as a string server-side using NodeJS and sent across the wire as complete HTML to be rendered. I'm in the process of adopting AngularJS, and while I'm loving it I am stuck on this issue-- how can I use Angular templating to insert invalid HTML at times?

The server will return three JSON fields: `leadingHTML, trailingHTML, and copy`. The `copy` field is always valid HTML, but leadingHTML and trailingHTML can sometimes return invalid HTML. When all three are added together, valid HTML results.

Let me illustrate:

```
leadingHTML='<figure>';
copy = '<img src="img1.jpg"/><img src="im2.jpg"/><figcaption>I love AngularJS</figcaption>';
trailingHTML='</figure>';
```

As you can see, if you add those together you will get the valid HTML that is required to be displayed. It's pretty easy to make the fields trustworthy HTML in Angular:

```
for (i in data.results){
    data.results[i].copy=$sce.trustAsHtml(data.results[i].copy);
    data.results[i].leadingHTML =$sce.trustAsHtml(data.results[i].leadingHTML );
    data.results[i].trailingHTML =$sce.trustAsHtml(data.results[i].trailingHTML );
}
```

And then render the `copy` in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat='i in data.result'>
    <p ng-bind-html='i.copy'></p>
</div>
```

But I need a way that does what this looks like it would do, but the leadingHTML and trailingHTML scope variables get render as strings:

```
<div ng-repeat='i in data.result'>
{{ i.leadingHTML }}
    <p ng-bind-html='i.copy'></p>
{{ i.trailingHTML }}
</div>
```

Is the best answer here to build the template via javascript? Would that even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to pre-process your data so that you do have valid HTML?

```
var item;
for (i in data.results){
    item = data.results[i];
    item.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.leadingHTML + item.copy + item.trailingHTML);
}
```

Then you can just bind to the combined content in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat='i in data.results'>
    <div ng-bind-html='i.content'></div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

Yes, this will allow you to embed expressions in your HTML content.

In fact, you will need to be careful that you aren't opening yourself up to security exploits in the trusted HTML content (see the [example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce#example) at the bottom of the page for the $sce service).

Using `$sce.trustAsHtml` in this way is roughly equivalent to loading a directive's `templateUrl` from your site, so the security considerations around that are probably the same. See the ["How does it work?"](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce#how-does-it-work-) and 
["Impact on loading templates"](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce#impact-on-loading-templates).

Comment: Right! I was doing that server-side in NodeJS anyway. Still new to Angular and suppose I was wondering if there was something I was missing. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Suppose I may need to update the question, but if my copy field needs binding... will this work? Say in my copy I need `<p ng-click="doClick()">some text</p>`. Will that automatically bind?

Comment: See my edit, but in short, yes it will allow binding expressions.

Comment: thanks for the fast help. New to the SO community but very glad I joined.